# Redondear número a dos decimales

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de redondear a sólo 2 decimales el valor de la variable **a** y el valor de la variable **calIntereses**. Utilizando aredondeado=round(a,2); me devuelve error.

```
double a;
double calIntereses;    
System.out.println("Año " + y);
System.out.print("    C.Inicial: ");
a=capitalInicial+(aportacion*(y-1))+calIntereses;
System.out.println(a);
calIntereses =a*(tasa/100);
System.out.println("    Intereses: " + calIntereses);
```

Comment: ¿De qué tipo son las variables?  ¿Qué error estás recibiendo?

Comment: son de tipo double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomendaría que uses la clase [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) para esto, incluso para tu valor de origen, ya que el tipo de dato `double` es problemático para fines de precisión.

Aquí se crea un `BigDecimal` a partir de tu valor `a`, luego se indica con `setScale` que quieres dos lugares decimales, y pasas un segundo parámetro `RoundingMode` que puede ser distinto según el tipo de redondeo que quieres ([ver aquí para entender cada tipo de redondeo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)).

```
BigDecimal mValue = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal roundValue = mValue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Sobre el problema de los dobles y la necesidad de usar `BigDecimal`, puedes consultar el artículo [*The need for BigDecimal*](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071332/the-need-for-bigdecimal.html), publicado por John Zukowski <s>en el blog de Oracle</s>, así como esta pregunta de Stackoverflow en inglés [*How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179427/5587982), sus respuestas y la pregunta de la que es duplicada. Como verás, el tema ha sido discutido ampliamente en la comunidad anglófona y las conclusiones son contundentes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar un formato usando la clase `DecimalFormat` , esto para que puedas imprimir el valor de `calIntereses` con 2 decimales.

```
double a;
double calIntereses;    
System.out.println("Año " + y);
System.out.print("    C.Inicial: ");
a=capitalInicial+(aportacion*(y-1))+calIntereses;
System.out.println(a);
calIntereses =a*(tasa/100);

//Formato con 2 decimales.
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("####.##");
//Aplica formato.
System.out.println("    Intereses: " + d.format(calIntereses));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres redondear te aconsejo usar la clase DecimalFormat de este modo:

Por ejemplo:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;// Importamos la libreria
class a{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("####.##");
        System.out.println(d.format(2.06846341));    
    }   
}
```

esto devuelve `2,0685` , donde los numerales que siguen después del punto (.) son la cantidad de decimales que quieres mostrar... Mientras mas decimales necesites, mas numerales tienes que agregar