# ¿Cómo convertir un valor float o double a precio monetario?

Tags: java, float, double, bigdecimal

Buenas Comunidad de Stack. 
Tengo un inconveniente para usar datos doubles para fines de precios, mi caso es que tengo cantidades de tipo float en mi base de datos pero cuando lo obtengo y lo multiplico por 2.77 mi precio total es $679.8965 pero yo solo quiero que me ponga solo los 2 primeros dígitos antes y después del punto.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo parsear el dato?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Redondear número a dos decimales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305148/redondear-n%c3%bamero-a-dos-decimales). Puedes consultar [también aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93015/29967). Y, si es posible, incluso en la Base de Datos declara tus datos del tipo `Decimal`, teniendo en cuenta hacer un backup de la BD antes de cualquier modificación masiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar DecimalFormat de esta manera

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(df.format(decimalNumber));
```

¿Pero tambien quieres solo 2 integers?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la clase **DecimalFormat** del paquete **java.text**. Por ejemplo:

```
    final float num = 679.8965f;

    final DecimalFormat moneyFormat1 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    System.out.println(moneyFormat1.format(num)); // Resultado => 679,90

    final DecimalFormat moneyFormat2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(moneyFormat2.format(num)); // Resultado => 679,9
```

Comment: Claro! si funciona, pero un detalle que se paso fue que era java pero para android y pero de igual me funciono para java de escriotrio.